# How to show the 1920px width version of website with iframe tag in a 720px width container 'Div'

Tags: html, css, iframe, tags, frontend

I have an iframe tag of a website with 1920px of width (desktop version), and i want to scale it to fit a 720px div container, without changing the iframe width because it will give me the tablet version, is it possible? thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`transform: scale();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale). You want to scale by 720 / 1920 = 0.375 = 37.5%.

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 720px;
  /* just a random height to make the resulting code snippet window not too big */
  max-height: 450;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px dashed lightgreen;
}

iframe{
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(37.5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <iframe src="http://example.com/" width="1920" height="1080">
  
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: @RafaelEchart You can mark my answer as the correct answer by clicking the tick on the left side of my answer. This way people and the system knows, that the problem is solved.